# How to change production certificate (.p12) after application is in appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, app-store, ssl-certificate

Certificates, provisioning profiles and setting Apple Push Notification is the part I could never grasp fully since first day. I believe a lot of people are having similar issues looking at SO questions. Unfortunately after long approval process and finally the app being in Appstore, my apps push notification is not working. While in development, the push notification was working perfectly. I guess I made a mistake in setting production certificates just before app store submission (most probably the reason was my frustration with this subject - or my lack of knowledge - we will find out..)

Now the technical part: 
[image: iOS App ID Settings]

I submitted my App with the APN certificate labelled as `1`. After we figured the PN are not working, I created the certificate labelled as `2`. I will talk about it later.

And here is the Keychain access screenshot from the computer I created the certificates from (The labels are matched with the above certificates image):
[image: keychain access screenshot]

As you can see, the certificate `1` doesn't have a private key attached to it. (Is this a problem?!) I don't know how it happened or if I have deleted it by mistake or never created it in the beginning. All the rest have private keys attached to the certificates.

Thinking that this must be the reason for the PN not working, After the app was in Appstore, I created a new APN certificate labelled `2`. This time with a private key attached:)

And here is how I export the certificate and private key couple to a .p12 file. I don't think this part is wrong since it is the same procedure I used for development .p12:

[image: .p12 exporting]

Whatever I tried, (I exported every possible .p12 combination of the 4 certificates and 3 private keys and embedded them to our server) Push notifications are not working.

So my question is:

Do I have to re-submit my app to the Appstore again with brand new certificates? This would be really bad since the people who downloaded the app will not have Push notification functionality for another at least 12 days. (thats how long it took Appstore to review last time)

Is there still a chance that I can play with the Apple Developer Console and alter/create new certificates/provisioning files/APN certificates and get this thing working without the need for a re-submission.

Thanks for reading the somehow long question. Any help/thought would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need of re-submitting the app. 
For certificate 1 - yes missing private key means certificate is not correct.
where as certificate 2 you can again export .p12 file or you can create a new certificate and create .p12 file.
and yes, you can play around for .p12 file.

Comment: I hope you are right about the re-submission being unnecessary. I will play around some more and let you know.